Question on notation in Extremal Combinatorics
In the following image, can someone please explain in detail the meaning of the $\sum$*(n,k) for me? I don't really see why the author mentions the following:
1.) What is the significance of whether $n + k$ is even or odd
2.) Why does $n + k$ parity imply one or two families?
The way I read the sentence "Let $\sum$*(n,k) be the collection of families consisting of the corresponding levels" is that some collection is being formed as the union of the highest k binomial coefficient levels. So for n = 5, k = 2 it would be 5 choose 2 = 10 and 5 choose 3 = 2 and so the resulting family is a collection of 20 sets, 10 of which have size 2 and the remaining 10 have size 3.
Clearly I am wrong, can someone explain this paragraph to me? Thanks in advance


It's because the larget binomial coefficient is not necessarily unique. For example in the row
$$
1,5,10,10,5,1
$$
the largest coefficient appears twice. That's when you have the duplication in $\Sigma^\ast(n,k)$ mentioned as the second case.

when he writes, "contains one family" does he mean one family per size? because there should be in total k families in the new family we are defining right?
